# Jqgrid filtering is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have filled my jqGrid using Ajax call. I have another dropdown on the page. Now I am trying to filter grid based on the value selected in the dropdown on one column `'FName'`. However grid is not getting filtered. Please see the code below and help me to fix it.

Grid Code:

```
$("#jqGridAppointments").jqGrid({
            url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
            mtype: 'POST',
            postData:
            {
                useMyFilter: "1",
            },
            datatype: "json",
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }
            },
            colNames: ['Emp id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Action'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'ID', dataField: 'ID', index: 'ID', key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'FName', dataField: 'FName', index: 'FName', width: 150 },
            { name: 'LName', dataField: 'LName', index: 'LName', width: 100 },
            {
                name: 'Edit', width: 50, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {
                    baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:',
                    showAction: "ShowEditscreen('",
                    addParam: "');"
                }
            }
            ],
            page: 1,
            sortname: 'ID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asce",
            caption: "Appointment Details",
            gridview: true,
            height: "auto",
            loadonce: true,
            search: true,
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
        });
```

Code for button click on which I am trying to filter grid:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
            var filtertext = $("#ddlList").val();
            var grid = $("jqGridAppointments");
            var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
            $.extend(postdata, { filters: '', searchField: 'FName', searchOper: 'bw', searchString: filtertext });
            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: postdata });
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
        });
```

One thing to note is, value of `postdata` variable in button click line 3 is coming as `undefined` when i debug the code. Could someone give me direction here as I am new to `jqGrid`?

Guys please help me on this as I am not able to move ahead.

Comment: can someone pls help on this.

Comment: Hey guys to answer yet on this??